# Android OutOfMemoryError AbstractStringBuilder on Json converter

Tags: java, android, json, bitmap, out-of-memory

On my app when I try to upload my database with 1 bitmap (String BASE64) I have this error.

One bitmap, that is already reduced to less than 1mb.

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 206980294 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 195MB until OOM
07-28 10:02:00.189 8431-9460/br.ufsm.cpd.ufsmreader D/Error: ERR: exMsg=Failed to allocate a 206980294 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 195MB until OOM
07-28 10:02:00.189 8431-9460/br.ufsm.cpd.ufsmreader D/Error: ERR: file=AbstractStringBuilder.java
07-28 10:02:00.189 8431-9460/br.ufsm.cpd.ufsmreader D/Error: ERR: class=java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder
07-28 10:02:00.189 8431-9460/br.ufsm.cpd.ufsmreader D/Error: ERR: method=enlargeBuffer line=95
```

I'm trying to do my upload like this (when there is no bitmap it works perfectly):

```
pws.getJsonArrayFromWS(Constants.UPLOAD_INVENTARIO, null, Utils.getDefaultGson().toJson(uploadInventario), true);
```

The error occurs on the

```
Utils.getDefaultGson().toJson(uploadInventario)
```

What could I do?

Comment: Failed to allocate a 206980294 byte, that's not 1mb

Comment: I know, but why is trying to allocate so much?? The database has 2 itens with 5 elements each.. All strings, longs, etc.. And one of then has the bitmap.

Comment: how big is the bitmap in pixels?

Comment: Lelloman, it's 144x256 px.

Comment: It is better to check the size of bitmap object and string object. like this:
`BitmapCompat.getAllocationByteCount(bitmap)` and `base64String.length()`

Comment: Nshmura, 147456 bytes and lenght=85604

Comment: Thanks, it is small enough. Can you post the class of `uploadInventario` and the size of `uploadInventario`'s each field?

Comment: It's really small, just for test I'm sending the uploadInventario with 2 itens, that has small strings and Longs for ID.

Comment: (Sorry for late response) That's odd... Can you tell me how to reproduce?

Comment: Don't know how to reproduce..